# How to set the id of a dd element in Zend_Form manually?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-form-sub-form

I have an image element in my Zend_Form.

```
$dropDownButton = new Zend_Form_Element_Image('image_button');
$dropDownButton->setOptions(array('image'=>'/images/image1.png',
                                'style'=>'padding-top:20px',
                                )
                                );
$this->addElement($dropDownButton);
```

The above image is serving as some form of 'submit' button.
the html output is:

```
<dd>
<input type="image" style="padding-top: 20px;" alt="" src="/images/image1.png" id="image_button" name="image_button">
</dd>
```

For all other Zend form elements, I get something like:

```
 <dd id="name-element"></dd>
```

How can I do the same in case of an Image Zend Form Element?

Is there a way I can set the id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this and it worked:

```
$dropDownButton->setDecorators(array
                                 (array('ViewHelper'),
                                 array('Errors'),
                                 array('HtmlTag',
                                        array('tag' => 'dd','id'=>'add_drop_down-element'))));
```

Output is:

> ```
> <dd id="add_drop_down-element"></dd>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I think `$element->setAttrib('id', 'my_id');` will work.

Comment: I tried that and it did not set the id of the <dd> element.
It however did change the id of the <input> tag inside, although thats not what i want.

Comment: ah sorry, I misunderstood your question. For what you want, your solution is the correct one :)